# How to block people from viewing source code?

Tags: html

So I take this class, and I'm way ahead of everyone else and a lot of people steal code from my website, I have already disabled right clicking but it's rather easy to get around this, is their any way to stop people from being able to view my source code?

Comment: Yeah don't have a website simple.

Comment: If they have access to your website they can see your html, limit their access to your site. Allow only access from specified ip addresses etc etc.

Comment: build a device and serve content to only that device ,this can make harder.:) actually keep a copyright notice that's good

Comment: @Popeye I bet you went to an accredited institution with a real student ethics policy and professors who would help you in times like this. And I bet if other students were stealing your work you could go to the professor with evidence to punish those wrongdoers.

Comment: I think you can't strop that completely as per w3c norms

Answer (score 2):

`tl;dr:` Nope.

You could look into [obfuscation](http://htmlobfuscator.com/), as well as [CSS](http://cssminifier.com/) & [JS](http://jscompress.com/) minification.

*"If you steal from one author, it’s plagiarism; Steal from many, it’s art."*

Answer (score 1):

No, if someone wants it, they will get it, you can make it harder but, you will just alienate your users from normal functionality, focus on your backend code.

If they steal your code, your lector will hopefully notice, either way they only hurt themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik the only way to hide your source code is if you put it on the server-side.
It is not possible from hiding client-side source code from users - sorry.

One suggestion would be stopping the user from right-clicking but that might cause you more problems...

Comment: And even this isn't going to help if you're trying to hide HTML. If the client can see it, they can get it no matter what you do. All you can do is make it more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You could render the html pages server side and convert them into images which get sent to the client. You could then have some image maps that handle clicking on the various locations.

Comment: although extreme, +1 for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a perfect solution (100% bullet proof) to protect your JavaScript code on the client side, however there are some tools on the market that can help you to protect your code:

**Code Compression/Minification (Usually don't protect the code)**

- Google Closure (Free)
- Uglify JS (Free)

**Code Obfuscation/Compression/Minification**

- JScrambler (Paid, but is on my opinion the best one on the market)
- Jasob (Paid)
- Stunnix (Paid, it seems to be outdated)

Hope this answers your question!